# xcode ios simulator: how to set focus on specific window

Tags: xcode, applescript, ios-simulator, simctl

I have `n` instances of xcode ios simulator and I want to switch a focus on instance with specified id.
I tried next things:

- Switching focus using "open": `open -a Simulator --args -CurrentDeviceUDID <id>`. But it opens the last focused simulator instance instead of the instance with passed id.
- Switching focus using simctl tool. I tried to open URL in the specific instance of the simulator `xcrun simctl openurl <id> "https://www.google.com"`, but it doesn't change the focus.
- using applescript - it still focusing on the last focused simulator instance:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Simulator"
    perform action "AXRaise" of window 0
end tell
```

Do you have any idea, how to do this?
[image]

Comment: If you want to use **System Events** and `perform action "AXRaise" of window ...` it needs to be the `name` of the _window_, not  a _number_ as you are currently trying to do it.

Comment: how can I get a name of the window?
Trying to do this: `set wList to every window whose visible is true`, and getting this `(*window id 54456, window id 54541, window id -1*)`

Comment: I've update my answer with some additional information. Please take a look and let me know if you have any questions about implementing its methodology into you own _code_.

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is one method that works for me:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Simulator"
    activate
    set winName to the name of ¬
        the first window ¬
            whose visible is true ¬
        and index is not 1
end tell

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    perform action "AXRaise" of ¬
        window winName of ¬
        process "Simulator"
```

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes you have two **Simulator** *windows* visible, and it will toggle raising between the two. Obviously this is just an *example* and you'll need to modify and incorporate the methodology into you own *code*.

In your *example* **AppleScript** *code*, **window** *n* refers to its **index** as in:

> **index** (integer) : The index of the window, ordered front to back.

<sup>The quoted line above is from the **AppleScript** *dictionary* for **Simulator** in **Script Editor**.</sup>

The *z-order* of **index** starts at: **1**

Using **System Events** and `perform action "AXRaise" of window ...` can be done by it's `name` *property* or it's `index` *property*.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: thanks, your example works as `Cmd + Tab`, but I need more complicated thing - I need to switch on window with a specified id. The problem is that windows id's order is changing each time when I'm switching to another window according to z-index.

Comment: RE: "thanks, your example works as Cmd + Tab, but I need more complicated thing" --  I understand that and it was merely an _example_ and not meant to be implemented literally.  -- RE: "The problem is that windows id's order is changing each time when I'm switching to another window according to z-index" --  The `id` _property_ and the `index` _property_ of a _window_ are two different things, and it's the latter that's relevant to the _z-order_ not the former. If you could clarify explicitly and specifically what your needs are, I'm sure I can give you better _example_ **AppleScript** _code_.

Comment: Re: "If you could clarify explicitly and specifically what your needs are, I'm sure I can give you better example AppleScript code."
I have several simulators on one mac OS machine and I need to execute some keystroke on one of these simulators, having UUID of the simulator. So I need to focus on the simulator with passed UUID, before keystroke executing. Thats why I want to understand how to switch focus between windows, using their ids.

Comment: @Rostislav Shtanko, How are you ascertaining the `UUID`, noting that the `window id` is not a `UUID`.

Comment: I can make a map: Simulator UUID -> Window id, saving this information when the simulator starts. So, I need to focus on the window, using id of this window. Is it possible?

Comment: RE: "I can make a map: Simulator UUID -> Window id, saving this information when the simulator starts." --  Could you provide the details of this? -- RE: "So, I need to focus on the window, using id of this window. Is it possible?" -- I want to say yes, however, do any of the _windows_  have the same _name_? If you would provide the details, to the "UUID -> Window id" that would be appreciated and then I can test the _code_ I'd write for this before posting it, thanks.